# IF FORMULAR TO CALCULATE VALUES BASED ON NUMBERS

Tags: sharepoint-list

Please i have been battling with a SharePoint list formula for hours now and id be glad if someone can help me out here.I have a number column named (composite score).I want the another calculated field(sustainability status) to auto generate input based on if (composite score)is  between 0.1 - 0.5, it should be *not sustainable* but if its between 0.6 - 1.0, it should be **sustainable** if there is no input in (composite score), the calculated field should be blank.

```
=IF([Composite score]<=0.5,"Not sustainable","sustainable")
```

i have tried the below formula but the (sustainability status) column is auto generating "not sustainable" if (composite score) is blank

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your formula to this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Composite score]), "",IF([Composite score]<=0.5,"Not sustainable","sustainable"))
```

It uses [ISBLANK](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/is-functions-f2eb6d53-1c84-49c4-9db9-83c94d20200e) function.

Comment: you are the best, It has worked. I love this forum you have solved my 4 hour problems in less than 5 mins..Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad it helped! Please don't forget to mark the post as Answered.

Comment: Thanks, sure i will